# String representing a path in Java is returned with double backslash to an ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, string, backslash

i'm trying to return a string from Java to an ajax call. The string contains the local path for an excel file that should be opened in the browser: ex: "D:\docs\file.xls"
The problem is that when in returned is returned with double backslash as follow: "D:\docs\file.xls"
I tried to use regex, both in Java and in javascript to correct this, but the path still remain the same with the double backslash.

The ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url : baseUrl + "autotest/process",
        type : 'GET',
        data : '',
        dataType : 'text',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        processData: false,
        success : function(data) {
            //Here data contain a path with double backslash \\
            //even if i try to strip out the \\ as follow:
            var str = data.replace(/\\/g, "\\");
           //str still have the double backslash \\
```

The controller in Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "app/process", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // code...

    // trying to strip all the double backslash
    String path = str.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\");
    // path still have the double backslash \\
    return path;
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to remove double back-slashes `\\` from `data`, then the regex you're using in the ajax call isn't correct.
It should be `/\\\\/g` instead of `/\\/g`:

```js
var str = data.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried your regex and the result is the same. Interesting enought is the fact that if i put the statement console.log('received: ', data); 
the output is printed correctly as received: "D:\docs\file.xls"
and this before the expression var str = data.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\"); is issued
Why?

Comment: Interesting. Can you log both str and data, after the call to replace ?
also, can you System.out.print the str and the path String before and after the call to replace in the back-end as well ?